# ConfigHelper.setThriftContact() undefined in cassandra v1.2

Tags: cassandra

I am trying out the example given in Cassandra Definitive guide, Ch 12. This statement gives error and I am not able to figure out the replacement for it:

```
ConfigHelper.setThriftContact(job.getConfiguration(), "localhost",  9160);
```

Also,

```
IColumn column = columns.get(columnName.getBytes());
String value = new String(column.value());
```

**column.value()** gives compilation error.
any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

The Cassandra Definitive Guide book is a poor resource at this point, as it is quite outdated.  Cassandra has changed a lot since then, as has Hadoop, so the Cassandra-Hadoop integration chapter is particularly unreliable.

Here's a complete working Cassandra config:

```
ConfigHelper.setRangeBatchSize(getConf(), 99);
final Job job = new Job(getConf(), "average");
final Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
ConfigHelper.setInputRpcPort(conf, "9160");
ConfigHelper.setInputInitialAddress(conf, cassHost);
ConfigHelper.setInputPartitioner(conf, "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner");
ConfigHelper.setInputColumnFamily(conf, conf.get(keyspace), conf.get(inputCF));
//get all records
SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate().setSlice_range(new SliceRange(ByteBufferUtil.bytes(""), ByteBufferUtil.bytes(""), false, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
ConfigHelper.setInputSlicePredicate(conf, predicate);

ConfigHelper.setOutputInitialAddress(conf, cassHost);
ConfigHelper.setOutputRpcPort(conf, "9160");
ConfigHelper.setOutputPartitioner(conf, "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner");
ConfigHelper.setOutputColumnFamily(conf, conf.get(keyspace), conf.get(outputCF));
```

The issue with your line:

```
String value = new String(column.value());
```

is attempting to pass it into the `String` constructor.  In older versions of Cassandra `column.value()` returned `byte[]`, but it now returns a `ByteBuffer`.  If the underlying data is in fact a string, you can use Cassandra's `ByteBufferUtil.string()` to decode it.  So your new line would look like this:

```
String value = ByteBufferUtil.string(column.value());
```

Comment: DataStax docs are good, and for Hadoop I can recommend [this](http://www.slideshare.net/rastrick/presentation-12982302).